# How to detect hard disk failure?

Tags: centos, raid, hard-drive, mdadm

So, one of my servers has a hard disk failure. It's running software RAID, the system locked up and according to `/proc/mdstat` (and `/var/log/messages`), it's really down:

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      104320 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md5 : active raid1 sdb5[1]
      2104448 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md6 : active raid1 sdb6[1]
      830134656 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1]
      143363968 blocks [2/1] [_U]
```

and

```
Nov  5 22:04:37 m38501 smartd[4467]: Device: /dev/sda, not capable of SMART self-check
```

**However**

when I do `smartctl -H /dev/sda`, it passes the test. It also passes the test with `smartctl --test=short /dev/sda`.

So, is `smartctl` a broken testing tool, or am I doing something completely off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an intermittent error with the drive electronics? That's the first thing that comes to mind. Be safe and replace the drive.

Comment: Yes, I will replace the drive, but then I don't see why it still passes the `smartctl` tests.

Comment: That's what "intermittent" means.